# How to fix bluetooth problem?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, mac, audio, bluetooth

I'd like to connect my bluetooth headphones to my computer. Unfortunately, my macbook pro thinks that my headphones are connected. When I go to the bluetooth menu, my headphones appear connected even though they are turned off and out of range.

I deleted the bluetooth preferences plist with this command

```
sudo rm -R /Library/Preferences/com.apple.Bluetooth.plist
```

I've also gone and option + clicked the bluetooth menu and hit reset and disconnect. I also shift + option clicked and hit debug reset bluetooth module and forget all devices.

Answer (score 1):

Try to do **SMC Reset** as this will help for

**General performance and functionality problems**: abnormally sluggish behavior despite no CPU or disk usage, external ports not working, airport & Bluetooth aren’t showing up, external devices are not being found, etc

Apple says you shouldn’t reset the SMC without first trying other troubleshooting tasks, such as force-quitting problematic apps and restarting your Mac. However, Apple doesn’t mention any negative consequences of resetting the SMC, nor any way to determine for sure if the SMC is glitchy without resetting it and noticing that the problem went away. I’ve reset my Macs’ SMCs many times with no apparent ill effects, and on the occasion that did, in fact, turn out to be the solution to a problem.

**How to do SMC Reset**

Shut down and unplug your Mac. On the built-in keyboard, press and hold the Shift, Option, and Control keys on the left side and press the power button and hold all of these down for 10 seconds, then release the keys. Connect the power adapter and then turn the Mac on normally.